# Enable AWS Redshift encryption to a running cluster with CloudFormation change set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to encrypt a running Redshift cluster with the CloudFormation change set. This doesn't migrate the existing data/tables to the encrypted cluster. Is there any way to migrate the data when enabled encryption with change set?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to do this from the console.

["Encrypt your previously unencrypted Amazon Redshift cluster with 1-click"](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/encrypt-amazon-redshift-1-click/)